# How to delete a file such that the delete is irreversable?

Tags: c++, windows, delete-file, erase

I want to delete a sensitive file (using C++), in a way that the file will not be recoverable.

I was thinking of simply rewriting over the file and then delete it, Is it enough or do I have to perform more actions ?

Comment: Kill it with fire! Burn the hard-drive! Shred the disk! Not the data, the *disk* (it may require some kind of industrial shredder). [Disintegrate the thing!](http://www.google.com/#q=hard+drive+destruction)

Comment: @Martinho +1, only then will recovery surely be impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an interesting paper:

http://www.filesystems.org/docs/secdel/secdel.html

It adresses some issues with overwriting of files. Especially you can't be sure that the newly written data was written to the same location and that it's impossible to recover data that was overwritten just a very few times or even once (on modern media).

Comment: Thanks, its a very interesting article, but still, I can't burn the hard drive every day, and I can't switch to another filesystem.

From what I understand there is no real solution using software.

Answer (score 4):

Worst case scenario, you can't be sure of having done it without physically destroying the drive. It's possible that you're running on a journaling filesystem, that keeps the original whenever you modify a file to allow disaster recovery if the modification is interrupted by power failure or whatever. This might mean that modifying a file moves it on the physical drive, leaving the old location unchanged.

Furthermore, some filesystems deliberately keep the old version around as long as possible to allow it to be recovered. Consider for example shadow storage copies on Windows, when you modify a disk block that's part of a file that's part of a system restore point, the new data is written to a new block, and the old one is kept around.

There's APIs to disable shadow storage copies for a file, directory or the whole disk (don't know the details, might require admin privilege).

Another gotcha is filesystem-level compression. If you overwrite a file with random data, chances are you make it less compressible and hence larger on disk even though it's still the same logical size. So the filesystem might have to relocate it. I don't know off-hand whether Windows guarantees to continue using the old blocks for the start of the new, larger file or not. If you overwrite with zeros, you make it *more* compressible, the new data might fail to reach as far as the end of the old data.

If the drive has ever been defragged (IIRC Windows nowadays does this in the background by default), then nothing you do to the file necessarily affects copies of the data in previous locations.

`shred` and similar tools simply don't work under these fairly common conditions.

Stretching a point, you can imagine a custom filesystem where all changes are journalled, backed up for future rollback recovery, *and* copied to off-site backup as soon as possible. I'm not aware of any such system (although of course there are automatic backup programs that run above the filesystem level with the same basic effect), but Windows certainly doesn't have an API to say, "OK, you can delete the off-site backup now", because Windows has no idea that it's happening.

This is even before you consider the possibility that someone has special kit that can detect data on magnetic disks even after it's been overwritten with new data. Opinions vary how plausible such attacks really are on modern disks, which are *very* densely packed so there's not a lot of space for residuals of old values. But it's academic, really, since in most practical circumstances you can't even be sure of overwriting the old data short of unmounting the drive and overwriting each sector using low-level tools.

Oh yeah, flash drives are no better, they perform re-mapping of logical sectors to physical sectors, a bit like virtual memory. This is so that they can cope with failed sectors, do wear-leveling, that sort of thing. So even at low level, just because you overwrite a particular numbered sector doesn't mean the old data won't pop up in some other numbered sector in future.

Answer (score 1):

0's and 1's aren't really 0's and 1's. Residual magnetism and other techniques (which I doubt are being used by the users you're trying to keep the contents from) can be used to recover data after it was overwritten.

Take a look at this [entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann_method), could be what you're looking for.

EDIT:

To back-up my statement:

> One standard way to recover data that has been overwritten on a hard
>   drive is to capture and process the analog signal obtained from the
>   drive's read/write head prior to this analog signal being digitized.
>   This analog signal will be close to an ideal digital signal, but the
>   differences will reveal important information. By calculating the
>   ideal digital signal and then subtracting it from the actual analog
>   signal, it is possible to amplify the signal remaining after
>   subtraction and use it to determine what had previously been written
>   on the disk.

Comment: It doesn't really matter that 0's and 1's _characters_ aren't really 0's and 1's _bits_. But +1.

Comment: I was talking about bits. A 0 bit is actually not a 0 bit... It has some residual information about what was located in that bit before...

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @Luchian: Gutmann wrote his paper in 1996, and in the paper itself he was very clear that his results varied by drive technology, and hence that the multi-pass overwrite actually required would also vary by drive technology. I no longer use any drives whose technology is identical to those available in 1996, everything is much denser now. So the applicability of the results is questionable - we can say that there are grounds to worry about residual signals, but we can't say that it is "standard" to recover them from modern drives unless someone has repeated the research more recently.

Comment: @Steve: it's been repeated, it's debunked. Magnetism is quantisized, and the unit of quantization is the magnetic domain. The "residual" essentially was a number of domains not flipping. With current disks and PRML technology, there are simply not enough magnetic domains per bit for a meaningful residual. You can't be differentiate the analog signal from the statistical noise anymore.

Comment: @MSalters: I think "debunked" is a little unfair, it's not Gutmann that became obsessive about the results of that specific study at that moment in time. But thanks, it's "deprecated", "obsolete", etc.

Comment: The information in this answer is wrong. The attack on (single-pass) overwritten data has always been entirely theoretical and the German IT magazine c't did extensive tests and interviewed with recovery laboratories to determine whether data could be retrieved. The answer wasn’t only negative – it was stated that even theoretically thinkable techniques via [STM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanning_tunneling_microscope) would have prohibitively high error rates that even single byte recovery is out of the question. – More info: http://www.nber.org/sys-admin/overwritten-data-gutmann.html

Answer (score 0):

You should overwrite it using some randomly generated bytes, using a decent random number generator or cryptographic function that generates garbage.

To be really sure all is overwritten, you could overwrite the same memory area of the deleted file several times.

Comment: Or just overwrite with any other bit pattern. Safe. Residual magnetism isn’t enough to restore large-scale data in practice.

Comment: Why random bytes rather than 0's?

Comment: Simply writing zeros over the file will do. Why complicate it with random number generators?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that "overwriting" a file actually writes to the same physical location on disk?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - I believe that is the real question in this case. Residual magnetism is a red-herring, and it is not particularly hard to just rewrite the file several times (or use the Gutmann method or whatever) if you have a way to guarantee that you are doing a physical write.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - certainly it doesn't if your file system is in flash with wear leveling.  Best to use encryption like TrueCrypt from the get go then you can just delete the file without concern.

Comment: @Amardeep: beware that if your passphrase can be tortured or injuncted out of you in future, then deleting a file on a TrueCrypt volume is no better than deleting it on an unencrypted drive. TrueCrypt does nothing on its own to prevent free space from being decrypted, given the key. Careful use of hidden volumes can help against the rubberhose attack, though.

Comment: @Steve Jessop - Yes the rubber hose attack is the most insidious.  I purposely didn't comment on key management and protection for that reason.  It's very difficult and there is no single answer for all situations.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for sure.

Delete the file first, then just start creating a file which would fill up the remaining spaces in disc . This will override all the data present in the disk then if you delete the the file you have created then it is safe to say that your file can't be recovered.

Instead of creating a single big file , creating many files with the same size or little less of the file you want to delete will be best. And repeating this for many times will increase the amount of data to overload.

Answer (score -1):

Its better to shred the data first before overwriting. So get the memory address and swap the locations. After that over write the data.

Comment: What makes you think this is better?  Or is it just a guess?

Comment: I don't think anything having to do with swapping memory addresses is going to help him get the hard drive to obscure old data.